# SSRS 2016 on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express

I have question about using SSRS 2016 on SQL Server 2014. First of all, I don't have much experience with Reporting Services.

Company uses SQL Server 2014 and they have a database on it (around 100 GB in size). I could install SSRS 2014 on this server (because they have licensed SQL Server 2014), but I want to use SSRS 2016, because it has many new features (web portal, mobile reports, custom design, KPI,..).

My idea is to install SQL Server 2016 Express version (it's free up to 10 GB) to install SSRS 2016 on it, only to store this two meta ReportServer DB and then connect to this production SQL Server 2014 database to create queries against it.

Is this acceptable solution? Are there any other possibilities or they must buy SQL Server 2016 license to upgrade their SQL Server?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: The functionality you get with SSRS 2016 on Express is much lower than you get with the full version (no scheduled reports or role based security for example). If the functionality within Express meets the needs, I can't see why not. [Reporting Services Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017#SSRS)

Comment: @Larnu I understand, thank you for explanation

Comment: It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.